Can I carry the key of an array element when passing it as argument to a function?
Given this array:
$food = [
          'meat' => ['beef','chicken'],
          'veg' => ['salad','onions'],
           ]

and this function
function foo($a) {
   print key($a);
}

invoking foo($food['meat']) returns 0 instead meat
Since I need to know which element I'm working on I can simply add another argument to the function, but I wonder if there's is a way to access the original key.
Thanks in advance.

What you are asking doesn't make sense, in what context do you want to find the key? in a loop? If you pass $food['meat'] to your function then the key is 'meat', you know it. give more information on what you are trying to do.

Yes, you need to add another argument. Your argument is only a list of values.

$food['meat'] is the indexed array ['beef','chicken'], which can be thought of as:
[
    0 => 'beef',
    1 => 'chicken',
]

This is why key($a) returns 0.
I.e., there is no longer any "parent" key associated with this subarray, you lose that information inside the function.
If you want to know what the key was, you'll have to pass it as a second argument:
function foo($key, $values) {
    echo "key is $key\n";
    echo "processing values: ";
    print_r($values);
}

foo('meat', $food['meat']);

Then you can very easily iterate:
foreach ($food as $type => $foods) {
    foo($type, $foods);
}

Or:
array_walk($food, fn($foods, $type) => foo($type, $foods));

